# Chrome update block flash autoplay - how avoid it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I embedded a youtube video in a html page. I use the youtube iframe API with Flash (in my case, I cannot use an HTML5 video). 
Since the last Google Chrome update, Chrome block the autoplay and avoid to play/pause  programmatically a video ( element.playVideo() not respond). (Everything is ok on others browsers)

The only way I found is to:

- Go into **Chrome preferences**
- Then hit **Show advanced settings...**
- Then hit **Content Settings**
- then under **Plugins**, select the 1st choice **Run all plugin content** (or choose a specific exception )

[image]

This solution is **TO COMPLICATED** for users, does someone have a solution without any user interactions?

Answer (score 4):

Two possible Solutions to avoid autoplay blocking in Chrome:

- Load flash swf file from same domain name. You could consider proxying if it's your own infrastructure, but I think it's not possible for Youtube api.
- Load the player with a bigger size (Try different resolutions). This might sound naive, but Chrome considers bigger video players as content and doesn't block auto playback.

Answer (score 1):

**As far as I know and think, this issue is related with embedded Flash Content from other domains**

What I think

- this is a security feature from chrome, something like IOS video start, when to start a video the user have to tap somewhere on page (there must be a real user event behind the first video play), in this way we assure the OS that we are agree to play the video
- I have almost the same problem, my flash video player is embedded in another page using an iframe, and to start the video I have to click again on flash player placeholder, and let chrome know that as a simple user I'm agree with playing that content which comes from another domain.

I think that the only  solution for this will be **HTML5 Video**, until then maybe **someone will come with an "workaround"**